# In The Solr, How can i index a plain text file that contained a special characters

Tags: indexing, solr, special-characters, plaintext

[image]

In The Solr, How can I index a plain text file that contained special characters

In the upper case, tried in The Windows environment.

And in The Linux environment, tried for document of example.

[image]

But I got failure too.

Comment: How are you submitting the file now? You'll have to submit it directly to the Extracting Request Handler if it's just a plain text file: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/uploading-data-with-solr-cell-using-apache-tika.html

Comment: I tried like that but got failure

Comment: maybe there is  somebody who help me at  somewhere :)

Comment: The error you're getting is that the extracting request handler wasn't found. The `gettingstarted` collection is only available if you start solr with the `-e schemaless` argument as shown in the documentation linked above. See the documentation as well for how to enable the extracting request handler for your own collections. Also, please add errors _as text_ and not as images, as images make it hard for those who can't see properly to understand what the question is, and makes it impossible to search for your error message.

Comment: Thanks MatsLindh. I succeeded for indexing to pdf, txt files in Linux. But i failed it in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks MatsLindh.
I succeeded in indexing to pdf, txt files in The Linux.
But I failed it in Windows.
My configurations for Extracting Request Handler was the same in both environments.
This is my solrconfig.xml file

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />
.
.
.
<requestHandler name="/update/extract"
            startup="lazy"
            class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="lowernames">true</str>
        <str name="fmap.content">_text_</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

And the failed my command in windows.

```
E:\work\private\JAVA\solr8>java -Dc=test -Dparams="literal.id=doc1" -jar ./bin/post.jar "./example/exampledocs/solr-word.pdf"
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/test/update?literal.id=doc1 using content-type application/xml...
POSTing file solr-word.pdf to [base]
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 (Bad Request) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/test/update?literal.id=doc1
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">400</int>
  <int name="QTime">0</int>
</lst>
<lst name="error">
  <lst name="metadata">
    <str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str>
    <str name="root-error-class">java.io.CharConversionException</str>
  </lst>
  <str name="msg">Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0xe5 (at char #10, byte #-1)</str>
  <int name="code">400</int>
</lst>
</response>
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/test/update?literal.id=doc1
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/test/update?literal.id=doc1...
Time spent: 0:00:00.064

Why did not run this in Windows?
```

Comment: It because argument of type. I had to put -Dauto or -Dtype=application/pdf argument to command.